# Output img.currentSrc of srcset using jQuery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, retina

I need to output the current source of an image using a jQuery alert:

```
alert($('.someclass img').attr('currentSrc'));
```

...however the alert is outputting undefined.

For reference, the mark-up is as follows:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <img srcset="http://example.com/A.png, http://example.com/A@2x.png 2x">
</div>
```

Comment: yeah because there is no currentSrc attribute attached to the image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`currentSrc` is a property not an attribute. Use `.prop('currentSrc')`

```js
$(function() {

  console.log($("img").prop("currentSrc"));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass">
    <img srcset="https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-1x.png, https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-2x.png">
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't work in IE11 :( Checking the img-object, can't find any currentSrc property. clearly... srcset isn't supported: https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset

Answer (score -1):

try alert($('.someclass img').attr('srcset'));

Comment: Thanks but this outputs the value of srcset as is appears in the mark-up. I'm specifically trying to output the currentSrc of srcset. I.e. What's the current source based on the set of sources?