# ie11 polyfill to load background image based on picture sourceset

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have written the following polyfill for ie so that I can use css `object-fit`:

```js
const $images = $('.object-fit');
const replacementClass = 'object-fit-replacement';

if ($images.length) {
  $images.each(function(index, item) {
    const $image = $(item);

    // this code will not run in IE if image is in the cache
    $image.on('load', function(e) {
      makeDiv(e.currentTarget);
    });

    // this code will run if image is already in the cache
    if (item.complete) {
      makeDiv(item);
    }
  });
}

function makeDiv(image) {
  const $image = $(image);
  const $picture = $image.closest('picture');
  let $div;
  let $parent;
  let imageSource;

  if ($picture.length) {
    $parent = $picture.parent();
    imageSource = $image.prop('currentSrc') || image.src;
  } else {
    $parent = $image.parent();
    imageSource = image.src;
  }

  $div = $parent.find('.' + replacementClass);
  if (!$div.length) {
    $div = $('<div class="' + replacementClass + '"></div>');
    $parent.append($div);
  }

  $div.css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSource + ')');

  $picture.hide();
  $image.hide();
}
```

```css
.object-fit-replacement {
  /* for test only */
  background-size:cover;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100" media="(max-width:768px)">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" media="(min-width:768px)">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="Test" class="image object-fit">
</picture>
```

However, it only seems to load the actual image source from the image tag.  Is there a way for it to respect the current source (taken from the correct media query in the picture tag) - I thought `$image.prop('currentSrc')` was meant to get it but doesn't seem to work in ie11 (if you look at it in chrome, it loads the correct background image)

Comment: I don’t think `currentSrc` is applicable for images, that is only for audio/video elements, no?

Comment: @cbroe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684814/output-img-currentsrc-of-srcset-using-jquery

Comment: Ah I see my mistake, ie11 doen't even support picture tags, so the browser-fit polyfill is going to have to include a polyfill for the picture tag too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to ie11 not being able to handle the picture element.  In the end, as I knew all the breakpoints on our site for the picture elements (and that they were not going to change as they were made by a server side helper), I just added on a bit of jquery to get the correct source from the the picture tag:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import elementHelper from '../helpers/element-helper';
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

$(() => {
  const $images = $('.object-fit');
  const replacementClass = 'object-fit-replacement';
  const $window = $(window);

  if ($images.length) {
    $images.each((index, item) => {
      const $image = $(item);
      let imageLoaded = false;

      // this code will not run in IE if image is in the cache
      $image.on('load', e => {
        if (!imageLoaded) {
          makeDiv(e.currentTarget);
          imageLoaded = true;
        }
      });

      // this code will run if image is already in the cache
      if (item.complete && !imageLoaded) {
        makeDiv(item);
        imageLoaded = true;
      }
    });
  }

  $window.on('resize', throttle(() => {
    $(`.${replacementClass}`).each((index, item) => {
      const $picture = $(item).prev('picture');
      console.log('resize', $picture.length)
      if ($picture.length) {
        $div.css('background-image', `url(${getPictureSource($picture)})`);
      }
    });
  }, 100));

  function makeDiv(image) {
    const $image = $(image);
    const $picture = $image.closest('picture');
    let $div;
    let $parent;
    let imageSource;

    if ($picture.length) {
      $parent = $picture.parent();
      imageSource = getImageSource($picture, $image);
    } else {
      $parent = $image.parent();
      imageSource = image.src;
    }

    $div = $parent.find(`.${replacementClass}`);
    if (!$div.length) {
      $div = $(elementHelper.createElement('div', replacementClass));
      $parent.append($div);
    }

    $div.css('background-image', `url(${imageSource})`);

    $picture.hide();
    $image.hide();
  }

  function getImageSource($picture, $image) {
    const imageSource = $image.prop('currentSrc');

    if (imageSource) {
      return imageSource;
    } else {
      return  getPictureSource($picture);
    }
  }

  function getPictureSource($picture) {
    // this assumes that the image helper has created the object fit picture tag and is using the standard 5 media queries
    const $sources = $picture.children('source');
    if ($sources.length === 5) {
      const windowWidth = $window.outerWidth();
      if (windowWidth < 380) {
        return $sources.eq(0).attr('srcset');
      } else if (windowWidth >= 380 && windowWidth < 767) {
        return $sources.eq(1).attr('srcset');
      } else if (windowWidth >= 767 && windowWidth < 1200) {
        return $sources.eq(2).attr('srcset');
      } else if (windowWidth >= 1200 && windowWidth < 1600) {
        return $sources.eq(3).attr('srcset');
      } else {
        return $sources.eq(4).attr('srcset');
      }
    }
    return  $sources.last().attr('srcset'); // this assumes sources are done normally with desktop largest last (default to dektop)
  }
});
```